# Overriding notifyDataSetChanged() not working

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I'm trying to override notifyDataSetChanged to simply call super.notifyDataSetChanged, but I want to force it to happen on the main UI thread.

I have

```
@Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }
```

But I get an error that `The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type Object`. What is causing this and what is the proper fix?

Comment: Please post the whole class, I think you have missed an `extends`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your adapter class is structured something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity mActivity;

    public MyAdapter(Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the point that you call `super.notifyDataSetChanged()`, you're in the context of the new anonymous `Runnable` class, so calling `super` is trying to find the superclass of that Runnable; not the Adapter, which is what you're expecting.

You need to qualify that you're looking for the `Adapter` class's superclass:

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MyAdapter.super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. +1 for the explanation!